# SyncAdapter not getting invoked from requestSync

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have a custom account, SyncAdapter and corresponding service etc. setup and working reasonably well on an emulator (Nexus 5X API 25). I am at present just trying to invoke the onPerformSync   manually for testing and understanding so I use the following code to  -

```
                Account acct  = getMyAccount() ;
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
                if(permissionsHelper.canDoCalendar()){
                    ContentResolver.requestSync(acct, "com.android.calendar", bundle);
                }else{
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Permissions not yet granted..Wont start syncadatper") ;
                }
```

This code works on the emulator but does not work on my real phone. ContentResolver.requestSync gets invoked but after that, nothing happens. I can use the debugger on emulator but the debugger on the physical device does not work after requestSync and neither do I see any errors or stack trace  - I have been looking at the logs without any filters to make sure I do not miss logs when they are emitted by other processes (although emulator does not run the adatper in a different process). I have not provided android:process option in the adatper service configuration.

Using targetSDK 25

Service configuration:

```
    <service
        android:name=".core.calendar.SyncAdapterService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/calendar_syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

SyncAdatper configuration

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="com.android.calendar"
android:accountType="xxxxxx" <-- removed for the time from post
android:userVisible="true"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
android:supportsUploading="false"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this setting:

```
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
```